# bcrypt.checkpw is not working as expected

Tags: python, bcrypt, streamlit

I have this issue, I been searching and I try everything I could find, but the issue persist. bcrypt.checkpw return false even when password is correct. In my database I have this in hashed password: `$2b$14$pQOcw.eOoood3v7svmIZt.3lhBjyHYfCoJB4jbaRqPGQvwI4iosGG`
and the password is "test101".

If I do the hashing and the checkpw in the same function, it works. But when I split the 2, hashing in register and checkpw in login. Then, it does not matter what I do, I can't make it return True. The password is the same as the one used in hashing. The database has the records stored correctly.

This is what is being use on the checkpw function, in the correct order:

```
hashed_password
<class 'bytes'>
b'$2b$14$pQOcw.eOoood3v7svmIZt.3lhBjyHYfCoJB4jbaRqPGQvwI4iosGG'
b'test101'
```

Here are the register and login functions, I'm using streamlit for UI and SQLite3 for database:

```
# Función de registrar
def register(database, nombre, password, email, matricula):
    try:
        conn = database.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        query = "INSERT INTO student (nombre, password, email, matricula, created_at, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.execute(query, (nombre,
                               bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt(14)),
                               email,
                               matricula,
                               datetime.now(),
                               True))
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False

    finally:
        conn.close()

    return True


# Función de login
def login(database, email, password):
    try:
        conn = database.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        query = "SELECT password FROM student WHERE email = ?"
        cursor.execute(query, (email,))

        hashed_password = cursor.fetchone()

        if hashed_password:
            print("hashed_password")
            print(type(hashed_password[0]))  # Debería imprimir <class 'bytes'>
            print(hashed_password[0])  # Debería imprimir el hash en formato bytes
            print(password.encode('utf-8'))  # Debería imprimir el hash en formato bytes
            if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password[0]):
                return True

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    finally:
        conn.close()

    return False
```

Here is the this table:

```
 cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                matricula INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                nombre TEXT NOT NULL,
                password TEXT NOT NULL,
                created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
                active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
                is_admin BOOLEAN NULLABLE              
            )
        ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

I was using to different hashing system. In my old system I was using

`hashed_password = stauth.Hasher([password]).generate(),`

to hash my password, before sending it to new system using my register() and checkpw using bcrypt.

So, I was double hashing, that's why checkpw did not return True. It didn't had the correct hash when validating.

So, when dealing with this issue, verify first if your not hashing with another function your password.

Thanks.